# WhatsApp is not initializing and not connecting

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I restore my mobile and try to reinstall WhatsApp. It is not initializing, but I am getting notifications. In a pop-up, it shows "unable to connect".

I have cleared my data. My internet connection is very fast.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to resolve it by doing the following for my android phone:

It seems to be a contacts sync issue.

For my Android phone (Note 20 Ultra from Samsung), what I did was the following:

1. Unlinked my google account that had contacts
2. Uninstalled and reinstalled whatsapp (might have done this first before step 2 also)
3. Went into the phone's settings --> accounts and backup --> manage account --> Whatsapp --> then proceeded to 'unsync' my account
4. Went through the login process again and somehow it did not need verification or it autoverified or something (can't fully recall)
5. It started initialising again and I am logged in
6. Had to link back my account to google to sync back contacts thereafter and turn on the 'sync contacts' settings again

There might be some backend issue on whatsapps end that doesn't sync well with the phones contacts on android.

Searched multiple online forums and a few suggested that it might be the contacts settings thus I trialed and error regarding the various settings.

Hope this helps if you have future people who encountered the same issue (i see multiple people online expressing it)

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have a fast and reliable internet connection.

If that doesn't solve the problem, try clearing App Data from `Settings -> Apps -> WhatsApp Messenger -> Clear Data`.

Comment: It doesn't work and it's still not connecting.